# Why my memory usage blow up after stopping a download？

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-core, memory-leaks, download

I an using the following codes to implements download a large file, it return a stream to the front-end, and using streamSaver to receive the stream and write to the local file in the front-end.

back-end:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Download() 
{
    var path = "D:\\backend-fileupload\\test.rar";

    var newstream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);

    var size = newstream.Length;

    HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length",size.ToString());

    return new  FileStreamResult(newstream, "application/octet- stream");
}
```

front-end:

```
        const name = "test.rar"

        const fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream(name, {

        size: Number(res.headers.get("Content-Length")) })

        const readableStream = res.body;

        if (window.WritableStream && readableStream?.pipeTo) {

            return readableStream.pipeTo(fileStream).then(() => {

                console.log('done writing...')

            })

        }

        const writer = fileStream.getWriter();

        const reader = readableStream?.getReader();

        const pump: any = () =>

            reader?.read()

                .then(res => res.done ? writer.close() : 

        writer.write(res.value).then(pump));

        pump();
```

But when I pause the download, the google browser memory usage blow up and then crashes. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.